# IE10 Script5009 - removing YouTube embed IFrame "'Array' is Undefined"

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I have a mini application and on some states of the application I embed a YouTube video as the source parameter of an IFrame:

Such as this:

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXVIDEO-IDXX?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=0`

See [Embed a player using an iframe tag](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

On IE10, once I destroy the iframe, I get a repeating console log saying:

`Script5009 - "Array" is undefined`

The code spawning this error loop appears to come from `html5player-new.js` and halts on this code. `for( var d = Array(arguments.length-1)...`

My question is 2 fold:

1. Is there a specific process I should follow when it comes to the removal of an IFrame or its parent element? (Especially in IE10).
2. Since `html5player-new.js` is throwing the error how can I track that back to my code? I am not suggesting the player is broken as it is used a million times a day, but I have 3 lines of code to create/src/add a iframe. Likewise an equal amount of code to remove it from the dom and null it so, that leaves me little to debug.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2 weeks since this question was written, the problem appears to have been resolved and I no longer get any errors on W8 and W7 with IE10.